# Cannot get country of user by php

Tags: php

I want to know country of user using my site by `PHP`, so I write this function to detect:

```
 $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/"));
```

I try with other links

```
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip={$ip}"));
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=$ip"));
```

I use these for 2 sites, one is staging and one is live (different server)

On staging it work perfectly. But on live it always return false. Why it happens? How can I get user's country on my live site?

Thanks >_<

Comment: Ever thought about Google analytics? https://analytics.google.com/

Comment: Couldn't resolve host 'api.hostip.info'.

Comment: Most of these free services have a limit on the number of calls you can make per Day/Hour! Are you exceeding some limit??

Comment: How many visits is your live site getting per day

Comment: Do you run this code once per ip address or on every page?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no any visits, because it still developing, not release yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents` would only work when `allow_url_fopen` is on in php.ini file.

For security reasons this is disabled on most of the production environments.

Either you should enable it in php.ini or use cURL (I would recommend to use cURL). ini setting are below:

```
; Disable allow_url_fopen for security reasons
allow_url_fopen = 1
```

Comment: Exactly, i use curl for this and it work. Thankssssssss

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
function getLocationInfoByIp(){
$client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote  = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$result  = array('country'=>'', 'city'=>'');
if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
    $ip = $client;
}elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
    $ip = $forward;
}else{
    $ip = $remote;
}
$ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));    
if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null){
    $result['country'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode;
    $result['city'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_city;
}
return $result;
```

}

http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-name-by-name.php

Comment: I already try it, return all info on staging and return false on live. I think some config on server block it :(

Comment: While this is a useful example, it's not suitable for a serious production website. The use of file_get_contents() prevents a reasonable timeout and error handling. If/when your site cannot connect to geoplugin.net, your site will go down.

Please use curl with reasonable timeouts and error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Try Another way :

```
<?php

function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
$output = NULL;
if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    if ($deep_detect) {
        if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
}
$purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
$support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
$continents = array(
    "AF" => "Africa",
    "AN" => "Antarctica",
    "AS" => "Asia",
    "EU" => "Europe",
    "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
    "NA" => "North America",
    "SA" => "South America"
);
if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
    $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
    if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
        switch ($purpose) {
            case "location":
                $output = array(
                    "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                    "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                    "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                    "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                    "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                    "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                );
                break;
            case "address":
                $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                    $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                    $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                break;
            case "city":
                $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                break;
            case "state":
                $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                break;
            case "region":
                $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                break;
            case "country":
                $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                break;
            case "countrycode":
                $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                break;
        }
    }
}
return $output;
}

?>
```

**HOW TO USE:**

```
<?php

echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Country"); // United States
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Country Code"); // US
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "State"); // California
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "City"); // Menlo Park
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Address"); // Menlo Park, California, United States

print_r(ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Location")); // Array ( [city] => Menlo Park [state] => California [country] => United States [country_code] => US [continent] => North America [continent_code] => NA )

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in two lines

```
$ip =(!ini_get('register_globals'))? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']:@$REMOTE_ADDR; //Get User Ip

$user_country = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=".$ip); //Get his country by IP
echo $user_country->geoplugin_countryName; //Et l'affiche enfin :p
```

An other details Like :

```
echo "City";
echo $user_country->geoplugin_city;
```

Je precise que ce code fonctionne certes, mais il est ineficace si le client est derriere un proxy.

On the other hand, if you want to go further to recover the loulous that hide behind a proxy
[sibheke lokhu ezingeni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest&pageSize=50)