# how to get variable from url that loaded with Java script in php?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, html-entities

i have this URL : 
http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=65883838195688438

i want to get all numeric data from this website .

e.g : 3.797 M

in this page all data refresh immediately.

i try :

```
$url = 'http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=65883838195688438';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
echo $html_encoded = htmlentities($data);
```

or :

```
$url = 'http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=65883838195688438';
echo $data = file_get_contents($url);
```

but i cant get numeric data .

both methods does not contain numeric data .

Comment: are you getting any error? what output you are getting?

Comment: @DileepKumar i get no error . i get white page .

Comment: Keep error reporting on and try again.

Comment: @DileepKumar it's on already !

Comment: @DileepKumar this website load data from java script . i think because of that i cant get data from website . is there any way to get data then parse data ?

Comment: Have you tried with CURL instead of `file_get_contents`. In most of production environments this method not allowed. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453256/cannot-get-country-of-user-by-php/44453908#44453908

Comment: @DileepKumar i use file_get_contents in other php sources . there is no problem with that .

Comment: The problem is not at your end, the problem can be from the link that you are trying to get content (tsetmc.com). They might have disabled the `file_get_contents` for security reasons as most production environment do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the JavaScript generating the page content. All necessary data is in the JavaScript code. Just take a look into page source.

Piece of code from the source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var TradeHistory=[['20170717','2633.00','2577.00','2565.00','2705.00','1679','26095164','68719004798.00'],['20170716','2577.00','2599.00','2550.00','2600.00','840','7655664','19725265524.00'],...
```

The data comes also from there: [IntraDayPrice](http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/chart/data/IntraDayPrice.aspx?i=65883838195688438), [instinfofast.aspx](http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfofast.aspx?i=65883838195688438&c=34%20)

Comment: this is history of past days . the table in left down corner . i want data from top div .

Comment: Did you try to take a look into requests from this page (on the Network tab in the browser inspector)?
For example these: 
www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/chart/data/IntraDayPrice.aspx?i=65883838195688438 and 
http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfofast.aspx?i=65883838195688438&c=34+

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$url="http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=65883838195688438";

$url_par=explode("?",$url);
$parameters= explode("&", $url_par[1]);
$getpar= array();
foreach ($parameters as $parameter)
{
    $par= explode("=", $parameter);

    $getpar[$par[0]]=$par[1];

}
print_r($getpar);
```

Comment: i think i explain wrong ! i need data from inside website . e.g : 3.797 M inside website http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=65883838195688438